# How to use $arrayElemAt operator in Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

$arrayElemAt new in MongoDB version 3.2.

```
db.users.aggregate([
{
 $project:
  {
     name: 1,
     first: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$favorites", 0 ] },
     last: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$favorites", -1 ] }
  }
}
```

])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DATAMONGO-1536](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1536) is about to add `$arrayElemAt` and other missing aggregation operators to Spring Data MongoDB for the [Ingalls](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-Ingalls) release. Meanwhile you can provide your own `AggregationExpression` to create whatever operation is needed.

For the above something like the following does the trick:

```java
project("name") //
  .and(context -> new BasicDBObject("$arrayElemAt", asList("$favorites", 0))).as("first")
  .and(context -> new BasicDBObject("$arrayElemAt", asList("$favorites", -1))).as("last");
```

Answer (score 7):

you can now use `$arrayElemAt` with [ArrayOperators.ArrayElemAt class](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/ArrayOperators.ArrayElemAt.html).

The above MongoDB projection would be traduced like the following for Spring Data Mongo:

```
project("name")
  .and(ArrayOperators.ArrayElemAt.arrayOf("favorites").elementAt(0)).as("first")
  .and(ArrayOperators.ArrayElemAt.arrayOf("favorites").elementAt(-1)).as("last")
```

Answer (score 3):

Even more concise, you can even use `$arrayElementAt` as follows:

```
project("name")
  .and("favorites").arrayElementAt(0).as("first")
  .and("favorites").arrayElementAt(-1).as("last")
```