# Why does Spring Data MongoDB reject a field name containing a $ in an aggregation pipeline?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

When creating an aggregate query on MongoDB using Spring Data's ***ProjectionOperation*** class, using field with the **"$"** (for example 'test$') character causes an **IllegalArgumentException**

Verifying the spring data mongodb sources, I noticed that in the constructor of the **AggregationField** class a cleanup of the field name is performed. [Fields.java Class](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/2.2.0.M1/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/Fields.java)

```
private static String cleanUp(String source) {

    if (Aggregation.SystemVariable.isReferingToSystemVariable(source)) {
        return source;
    }

    int dollarIndex = source.lastIndexOf('$');
    return dollarIndex == -1 ? source : source.substring(dollarIndex + 1);
}
```

The nomenclature of the fields in MongoDB discourage the use of the "$" character or this is a Spring Data problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [reference documentation clearly states](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Restrictions-on-Field-Names) that it's currently not supported by the official MongoDB drivers:

> IMPORTANT
>
> The MongoDB Query Language cannot always meaningfully express queries over documents whose field names contain these characters (see SERVER-30575). Until support is added in the query language, the use of $ and . in field names is not recommended and *is not supported by the official MongoDB drivers*.
>   {quote}

I.e. Spring Data cannot support that until support for that makes it into the official Java driver.

Comment: Thanks Oliver.
I only ask you one thing, why in the "cleanUP" method do we do a "substring" from the last "$"?

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be a Spring data Mongodb problem... Your field name should be allowed.

> You can use any (UTF8) character in the field name which aren't special (contains ".", or starts with "$").

*source:* [SERVER-3229](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3229?focusedCommentId=36821&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-36821)

You could give it a try building your project operation using [BasicDBObject](http://api.mongodb.com/java/2.0/com/mongodb/BasicDBObject.html). Here is one example: [How to use $arrayElemAt operator in Spring Data MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40909320/how-to-use-arrayelemat-operator-in-spring-data-mongodb/53611651#53611651)